# Why does the ECHO command in a batch file FOR /F Loop always return "ECHO is on."?

Tags: windows, for-loop, command-prompt, subshell

Why does the `ECHO` command in the following batch always returns `ECHO is on.`?

```bat
@ ECHO ON
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`ECHO`) do (set EchoState=%%a)
@ SET EchoState
@ ECHO OFF
ECHO
@ ECHO for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`ECHO`) do (set EchoState=%%a)
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`ECHO`) do (set EchoState=%%a)
@ SET EchoState
```

The Output from this batch file is

```bat
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %a in (`ECHO`) do (set EchoState=%a )
    
(set EchoState=ECHO is on. )
EchoState=ECHO is on.
ECHO is off.
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %a in (`ECHO`) do (set EchoState=%a)
EchoState=ECHO is on.
```

Line 5 Prints what you would expect `ECHO is off.` because it is indeed off due to line 4

Why does the `ECHO` command in this batch file `FOR /F` Loop always return `ECHO is on.`?

Answer (score 0):

`for /f` runs the specified command in a subshell. Since in the new shell `echo` is turned on, it'll report `"ECHO is on"`

> This is because the FOR command will start the program in a new sub-shell which removes the outer set of double quotes.
>
> https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

You can easily see that by spawning a new shell

```
@echo off
echo
@cmd /c "echo"
```

The output would be similar to the above

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean its not possible to identify whether echo is Off or On?

Comment: @PeterNimmo obviously yes, echo is always on when starting a shell, unless you turn it off by `cmd /Q`. If you want to get the parent shell's echo status then pass it to the subshell